# Eloquent relationship in Laravel(7)

Tags: database, laravel, view, model, relation

I'm working on school's project using Laravel

- school has many class
- class has many subject
- subject has many lesson

  my Models : School ,Class ,

  ```
            Subject (contain class_id),

            Lesson  (contain subject_id)
  ```

my question is :

My final view(addLesson) must contain :

Select class , Select Subject , and Lesson's details

so how can I do that and save lesson to its class and subject
what relation do I need and how to do that

Comment: Use just `hasMany` relationship one by one

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: ok , I've already use hasMany relatioship but my problem is when I select some class where do I save it ? do I need to add (class_id) column to Lesson model ?

Comment: @Matrix no `class_id` column to lesson model. `class_id` in your subject model. and `subject_id` in your lesson model

Comment: i really do that , but to show classes name in my AddLesson I used ( $classes = Myclass::all();) in my controller and just make foreachloop in view , sorry I have some misunderstanding

Comment: how can I use relation to show classes in my view

Answer (score 0):

School.php

```
public function classes(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Class');
}
```

Class.php

```
public function subjects(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Subject');
}

public function school() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
}
```

Subject.php

```
public function lessons(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson');
}
public function class(){
   return $this->blongsTo('App\Class');
}
```

Lesson.php

```
public function subject(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Subject');
}
```

migrations

class migration:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('school_id');
```

subject migration:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('class_id');
```

lesson migration:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('subject_id');
```

when saving a class you need to save the `school_id` //
when saving a subject you need to save the `class_id` //
finally about your question
when saving a lesson u need to send the `subject_id` in the request
then in controller

```
$subject = Subject::find($request->subject_id);
$subject->lessons()->save([
 // lesson data
]);
```

this will save the lesson to the subject
hope this works for you :)